# Why does compressed WIF generate a different address when importing to a wallet

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptocurrency, key-generation

I have a compressed WIF private key starting with K but when ever i try to import it gives a different address. What could the issue be. The address generated is correct for the private key as i do have the screenshot as well when it was generated back in 2018 using a well known python script. Everytime i try to convert the Compressed WIF i keep getting a new address but not the old one